# laravel returns users not in array but in object nested in object

Tags: laravel

I am having a problem that i really can not understand. I am getting users in laravel where the role of the user is an admin or either a user. So when I am calling the users with the user role i am getting this (what I want):

```
[ { "id": 8, "username": "user", "firstname": "user", "lastname": "user", "email": "user@test.com", "email_verified_at": null, "phone_number": 6282223, "role": "user", "companyID": 1, "companyRole": "employee", "logged_in": 0, "created_at": "2021-11-03T15:25:29.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-11-03T15:25:29.000000Z" }, { "id": 9, "username": "manager", "firstname": "manager", "lastname": "manager", "email": "manager@test.com", "email_verified_at": null, "phone_number": 623423, "role": "user", "companyID": 1, "companyRole": "manager", "logged_in": 0, "created_at": "2021-11-03T15:25:29.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-11-03T15:25:29.000000Z" } ]
```

But when I call users with the role admin I am getting this (what i dont want):

```
{ "2": { "id": 10, "username": "mo", "firstname": "moemm", "lastname": "hus", "email": "hus@test.com", "email_verified_at": null, "phone_number": 6283, "role": "admin", "companyID": 0, "companyRole": "admin", "logged_in": 0, "created_at": "2021-11-03T15:25:29.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-11-03T15:25:29.000000Z" } }
```

I littarly have the sme code for both but the only thing that changes is that i am calling different roles

```
public function getAllUsers(Request $request){
        $users = User::all()->where('role', 'user');
        return $users;
    }

public function getAllAdmins(Request $request){
        $admins = User::all()->where('role', 'admin');
        return $admins;
    }
```

And this is my api route for the both functions:

```
Route::get('/admins', [UserController::class, 'getAllAdmins']);
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'getAllUsers']);
```

Comment: Don't use `::all()->where()`; that loads *everything* from your `users` table, then does PHP array filtering... That's inefficient. Do `User::where()->get()`, and you'll fix your issue, and your code will be more efficient. Also, you don't need to assign a variable if all you're doing is returning... `return User::where(...)->get();` works just as well.

Comment: Also, the reason this is happening is because JSON arrays are not associative, so they must begin with index 0 and increment from there. You are filtering the array so that the index begins at index 2. Since this isn't a valid JSON array, it is converting it to an object with a key of 2.

Comment: ^ This is 100% correct. To add though, if you did need to do `::all()->where()` (or, a more realistic example, `->get()->filter()`), you simply need to add `->values()` to convert it to a 0-based array, so `User::all()->where(...)->values()` would also fix your issue, but is still less efficient.